# (Python) How can i convert byte string into a raw string with double quote as

Tags: python, escaping, character

I have this byte represented as string:

```
b'google-site-verification=pFgmIQ6qK3YjcRAAhsKiPzmEiOVcynQslFMEba5lXvs'
```

I want to convert it to a raw string looking like this:

```
r'"google-site-verification=pFgmIQ6qK3YjcRAAhsKiPzmEiOVcynQslFMEba5lXvs"
```

(without the r' displaying on printing)

I tried it with replace but can't figure out to get it to work.
Maybe someone can help me here.

Greetings

Edit full code:

```
def decode_txt_rdata(rdata, rdlen):
    """decode TXT RR rdata into a string of quoted text strings,
    escaping any embedded double quotes"""
    txtstrings = []
    position = 0
    while position < rdlen:
        slen, = struct.unpack('B', rdata[position:position+1])
        s = rdata[position+1:position+1+slen]
        s = '"{}"'.format(s.replace(b'"', b'"').decode())
        txtstrings.append(s)
        position += 1 + slen
    return ' '.join(txtstrings)
```

Comment: I think if you have an extra single quote, i.e. `r'"` should be `r"`.  Anyway you can the **decode** function, as in `b'google-site-verification=pFgmIQ6qK3YjcRAAhsKiPzmEiOVcynQslFMEba5lXvs'.decode("utf-8")` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)

Comment: I use `s = '"{}"'.format(s.replace(b'"', b'"').decode())` to convert to string, but then it does not ignore backslash characters like \010 and take them as escape characters.
When I use decode('unicode-escape') the original byte string gets changed aswell at the backslash character.
I don't know what to do...

Comment: `r'"google-site-verification=pFgmIQ6qK3YjcRAAhsKiPzmEiOVcynQslFMEba5lXvs"` does not seem to be a valid string.

Comment: Did you try just `b'google-site-verification=pFgmIQ6qK3YjcRAAhsKiPzmEiOVcynQslFMEba5lXvs'.decode(("utf-8")`?  If so, is the result different from what you want?

Comment: It tells me `'str' object has no attribute 'decode'` and when I use it before converting to a string I get: `google-site-verification=Y3dKKFu_H3cJ3l66OBt0QIUL3
Z6cXR0UxhulSdc28lY` still with line break..

Comment: @asdfyxcvqwer--placed the code in an answer to ensure we are testing with the same code.

Answer (score 0):

**Use from first answer of**

[Convert Bytes to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string)

> **Assumption**
>
> Desired is:
>
> r"google-site-verification=pFgmIQ6qK3YjcRAAhsKiPzmEiOVcynQslFMEba5lXvs"
>
> NOT (which is not valid):
>
> r'"google-site-verification=pFgmIQ6qK3YjcRAAhsKiPzmEiOVcynQslFMEba5lXvs"

```
# Byte String
s = b'google-site-verification=pFgmIQ6qK3YjcRAAhsKiPzmEiOVcynQslFMEba5lXvs'

# String
decode_s = s.decode('utf-8')

print(f"Byte string\n\t{s}\n\n")
print(f"Decoded Byte string\n\t{decode_s}\n")
print(f'Is decoded == Desired \n{decode_s==r"google-site-verification=pFgmIQ6qK3YjcRAAhsKiPzmEiOVcynQslFMEba5lXvs"}' )
```

**Output**

```
Byte string    
    b'google-site-verification=pFgmIQ6qK3YjcRAAhsKiPzmEiOVcynQslFMEba5lXvs'

Decoded Byte string    
    google-site-verification=pFgmIQ6qK3YjcRAAhsKiPzmEiOVcynQslFMEba5lXvs

Is decoded == Desired
    True
```